# React; cannot read property of undefined inside render > return()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a simple React project that in short is like a little restaurant. And the restaurant can only serve certain dishes when all ingredients are available.

So I wrote something to check for each dish that all ingredients are available / true. But within my JSX I am getting the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined` (screenshot provided).

However where you can see I have a console.log at `// 1.`, the status property is defined.

Link to my public repo: https://github.com/danny-faith/dynamenu/tree/update/ingre-object

Use `update/ingre-object` branch

Ingredients object

```
const ingredients = {
  egg: {
    status: true
  },
  beef: {
    status: false
  }
}
```

Menu object

```
const food = {
  item1: {
    name: "Spaghetti Carbonara",
    desc: "With egg yolk and guanciale",
    price: 1724,
    ingredients: ['spaghetti','egg','pancetta'],
    status: "available"
  }, ...
}
```

Code insinde JSX

```
{
    Object.keys(this.state.menu).map(key => {
        console.log(this.state.ingredients['egg'].status); // 1.
        if (menu[key].ingredients.some(val => this.state.ingredients[val].status === true) ){
            return <MenuItem key={key} data={menu[key]} />
        }
    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: if you console.log(menu[key].ingredients) after your //1 log is it ok?

Comment: @GiannisMp - yes and I get `(1) ["egg"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see where you set your state , but this error can simply be avoided by adding checks `state.ingredients` like below.

```
if (menu[key].ingredients
              .every(val => {
                   return this.state.ingredients[val] ? 
                      this.state.ingredients[val].status === true : 
                      false;
              })){
            return <MenuItem key={key} data={menu[key]} />
}
```

A better practice would be to take the if condition to a separate function.

EDIT, added extra closing parenthesis to complete .some() function.

Comment: I set state a little further up outside the render() menthod, but state is all cool and I can log state out with no problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nuru, but I'm getting `Failed to compile` after replacing my `if` with yours.

Comment: @danielblythe it fails because there was an error. CAn you try my update ?

Comment: Hi Nuru, thanks, this stops the error from occurring. However it renders the menu item if any one of the menu item ingredients are present. See Daniele's reply for the actual structure of of the menu item ingredients. I also posted a link to my repo in my original post. So you'll notice that the menu item renders when egg is true, but Carbonara requires `spaghetti` and `pancetta`

Comment: Ok I changed .some() to .every() and that seems to have solved the issue I just pointed out above. Issue seems to be solved. Thanks!

Comment: Oh yah , i miss the word "every" in your comment. But regardless you can achieve that with some as well. You just need to tweak the condition .

Answer (score 1):

Since you are mapping an object maybe the problem is not on the specific ingredient that you log.

I think `Cannot read property 'status' of undefined` referred to `this.state.ingredients[val].status` depends on a `val` that is not defined on your `ingredients` object nested in one of the `menu` properties.

**You probably have a menu ingredient that is not present in the ingredients.**

*[EDIT]*

Looking at your repo I see:

```
item1: {
    name: "Spaghetti Carbonara",
    desc:
      "With egg yolk and guanciale",
    price: 1724,
    ingredients: ['egg','spaghetti','pancetta'],
    status: "available"
},
...
```

And your ingredients are:

```
const ingredients = {
  egg: {
    status: true
  },
  beef: {
    status: false
  }
}
```

So, for instance, `ingredients['spaghetti']` or `ingredients['pancetta']` are **undefined**.